# SAS averaging into groups

Tags: sas

Ive got 50 columns of data, with 4 different measurements in each, as well as designation tags (groups C, D, and E). Ive averaged the 4 measurements... So every data point now has an average. Now, I am supposed to take the average of all the data points averages of each specific group.

So I want all the data in group C to be averaged, and so on for D and E.... and I dont know how to do that.

```
avg1=(MEAS1+MEAS2+MEAS3+MEAS4)/4;
avg_score=round(avg1, .1);
run;
proc print;
run;
```

This is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are several procedures, and SQL that can average values over a group.

I'll guess you meant to say 50 **rows** of data.

Example:

`Proc MEANS`

```
data have;
  call streaminit(314159);

  do _n_ = 1 to 50;
    group = substr('CDE', rand('integer',3),1);
    array v meas1-meas4;
    do _i_ = 1 to dim(v);
      num + 2;
      v(_i_) = num;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop num;
run;

data rowwise_means;
  set have;
  avg_meas = mean (of meas:);
run;

* group wise means of row means;
proc means noprint data=rowwise_means nway;
  class group;
  var avg_meas;
  output out=want mean=meas_grandmean;
run;
```

rowwise_means

[image]

want (grandmean, or mean of means)

[image]